# Equivalent of git stash in CVS?

Tags: cvs, git-stash

I need to test some old version of our source code, however I have some local changes. So I would like to "stash" these changes, checkout the old version, do some tests, then go back to the current version, and restore my changes. Is it possible to do this kind of workflow in CVS? Basically, what I need is the equivalent of `git stash/restore`.

Comment: `git-cvsimport`? There's no stash functionality in CVS that I know of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CVS is primitive in comparison to modern source control systems.  There is no direct equivilent to stash.

The closest you'll get is using `cvs diff -u` to create a unified diff of your changes, then revert the changes, do whatever you need to do, revert / update again, then apply the patch to get your changes back.

Alternatively, you could just create another checkout in another directory and work there independently.

Comment: Another checkout is probably the easiest way unless you have a rather large source tree.  CVS is designed for all working trees to share one repo.

Comment: Just for the record, in Intellij you can [Shelve and unshelve changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html)